# Can't connect to mysql with unix_socket after using su

Tags: mysql, unix, mariadb

I'm running a localhost MySQL/MariaDB server on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, and I've configured two users, `shwang@localhost` and `app@localhost` to be authorized by the `unix_socket` plugin.

As expected, I can authenticate myself with unix_socket when I'm logged into my own account.

```
shwang@grimoire ~ % mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3817
Server version: 5.5.44-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

However, when I use `su` to switch the snorby user, MySQL seems to think that I am still `shwang@localhost`.

```
shwang@grimoire ~ % sudo su - snorby

app@grimoire ~ % mysql
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'shwang'@'localhost'

app@grimoire ~ % mysql -u snorby
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'snorby'@'localhost'
```

Am I missing something here? Should `unix_socket` really recognizing me as `shwang` when I `su` into `snorby`'s account?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Linux that is complaining, it is MariaDB.  You apparently have not `GRANTed` access `TO shwang@localhost`.